# Can I convert my application to any language? 

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4

I am doing R & D on this Topic. How can I change any language of my application from English?

For example, My Application is in English and now I want to change it in to any local language like Hindi, Gujarati, Sanskrit. So is it possible with iPhone/iPad. If yes then  please give me brief idea. I know the localization but don't know it support other languages or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of supported languages is listed here:

http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html

> English (U.S.), English (UK), French (France), German, Traditional
>   Chinese, Simplified Chinese, Dutch, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese
>   (Brazil), Portuguese (Portugal), Danish, Swedish, Finnish, Norwegian,
>   Korean, Japanese, Russian, Polish, Turkish, Ukrainian, Hungarian,
>   Arabic, Thai, Czech, Greek, Hebrew, Indonesian, Malay, Romanian,
>   Slovak, Croatian, Catalan, and Vietnamese

Although this list changes with new OS releases.

For more information about localising an app, you should take a look at the Apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html